# Pillow: write tiled TIFF

Tags: python-3.x, python-imaging-library, tiff

Is it possible to write a tiled TIFF image with Pillow?

Looking at the [docs](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/image-file-formats.html) there is mention of tiles for JPEG2000, but not for TIFF.

I know that the underlying libtiff allows for writing tiled images, is that exposed in Pillow?

This naive attempt does still write in strips:

```py
image.save(
    tif, compression="jpeg", quality=90,
    subsampling="4:2:2", optimize=True,
    tile_size=(256, 256),
    icc_profile=profile_fpath,
)
```

Comment: did you find out? I am curious if this is supported.

Comment: I never did. I moved to pyvips instead,which has tile and pyramid support, aside from being much faster.